# Building and using new data types in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing, python-dataclasses

How do you build custom data types in Python (similar to how you define `interface` in TypeScript)?

Let's say for example I have a class which accepts two input arguments. Both are optional, but one of them is required to initialize the class.

I can do something like:

```py
@dataclass
class Interface:
  a: Optional[str] = None
  b: Optional[int] = None

  def __post_init(self):
    if self.a is None and self.b is None:
      raise ValueError('one of a or b is required')
```

Now I want to define a function which accepts an argument of the type `Interface`:

```py
def func(i: Interface) -> Interface: 
  return i
```

Of course, this works if I invoke:

```py
func(Interface('abc')) # works
func(Interface(2))     # this does not work!
```

Is it possible to call the function similar to how you would initialize the `Interface` class? E.g.:

```py
func('abc')   # should work
func(2)       # should also work
func([1, 2])  # should report a type issue
```

The reason for doing this is that I have to make extensive use of the `Interface` "type", and would like to avoid writing the types everywhere.

Comment: The problem is that the *positional* argument `2` is assigned to `a`; type hints have no runtime effect.

Comment: Ideally, dataclasses would provide support for keyword-only parameters in `__init__`, so that neither `Interface('abc')` nor `Interface(2)` would be legal; you would be required to write `Interface(a='abc')` and `Interface(b=2)`. Remember: explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: @chepner: As of 3.10 they do, you use `@dataclass(kw_only=True)` as the decorator. They also added support for automatic `__slots__` generation (which was a *really* hard thing to do reliably pre-3.10), via `slots=True`.

Comment: Good grief, how did I miss that...

Comment: "How do you build custom data types in Python" by defining a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current definition still requires the arguments to match properly with the generated `__init__`, which has a form like:

```
def __init__(self, a: Optional[str] = None, b: Optional[int] = None):
    ...
```

When you do `func('abc')` it works because it's like invoking `__init__` with `'abc'` for `a` and `None` for `b`, so the types match. When you do `func(2)`, it's still trying to pass `2` to `a`, not `b`, so the types don't match and you get a (correct) error.

As currently, you must replace `func(2)` with `func(b=2)` or `func(None, 2)`.

If you want to do it with a single positional argument that can be either, you either:

1. Have to store both in the same field, e.g.:

   ```
   @dataclass
   class Interface:
       a: Optional[Union[str, int]] = None  # On modern Python, a: str | int | None = None would work

   # No postinit needed
   ```

   with the downside being that now you don't know which is stored there, and have to check each time, or...
2. Manually write `__init__` instead of relying on `dataclasses` to generate it, so it accepts a single value and stores it in the correct field:

   ```
   @dataclass
   class Interface:
       a: Optional[str] = None
       b: Optional[int] = None

       def __init__(self, ab: Optional[Union[str, int]] = None):
       # Or cleaner 3.10+ syntax:
       def __init__(self, ab: str | int | None = None):
           self.a = self.b = None
           if isinstance(ab, str):
               self.a = ab
           elif isinstance(ab, int):
               self.b = ab
           else:
               raise TypeError(f"Only str or int accepted, received {type(ab).__name__}")

   # No postinit needed
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I think I'll use the second option of manually checking in the `Interface` class, rather than having to do the check everywhere. But this still does not solve the issue of calling `func(i: Interface)` right? 
Pylance still reports a a TypeIssue when I call `func(2)` or `func('a')`

Comment: @besi: I missed that component. For case #2, you could declare `def func(i: Interface | str | int):` and have a precheck with `if not isinstance(i, Interface): i = Interface(i)` (the code for #1 where it maintains two separate arguments would be uglier). Type annotations are for static analysis though, they're not checked at runtime, and implicit type conversions aren't a thing, you *you'd* have to convert to `Interface` inside the function, you couldn't call with `func("abc")` and receive `Interface("abc")` "for free" (decorator magic could be used, but ugh, not worth it).

Comment: thanks again @ShadowRanger. I was trying to avoid writing a decorator, but I need to reuse this logic, so I don't think I have a choice. 

I'll accept your answer since it does answer my question. I think what I was hoping for was something like dict deconstruction. That is, define a dict `T` containing the types of `a` and `b` and then pass that to the function definition: `def func(i: **T)`, but this does not seem to be supported :(

Answer (score 0):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional


@dataclass
class Interface:
    a: Optional[str] = None
    b: Optional[int] = None

    def __post_init__(self):
        if self.a is None and self.b is None:
            raise ValueError('one of a or b is required')
```

First issue, is you have your `__post_init__` written as `__post_init`. If it is not written correctly, then it won't run after the class is instantiated.

Secondly, I am not sure the purpose of the `def func`, so I have ignored it for my examples.

Thirdly, the way the dataclass works is when instantiated, the first parameter is mapped to the first property in the class, unless you override it with explicit parameter names. Therefore in order to instantiate a class with just an int, you should do `Interface(None, 3)` or `Interface(b=3)`.

Therefore this is what will happen:

`Interface("abc")`  # works with just a string

`Interface("abc", 3)`  # works with both

`Interface(b=3)`  # works with just an int

`Interface()`  # raises an error as expected

`Interface(None, None)`  # raises an error as expected

`Interface(a=None)`  # raises an error as expected

`Interface(b=None)`  # raises an error as expected

Its worth mentioning that you will not have a warning that either of these parameters are required

However, in case you need this code to work, I have made a basic version of what you were trying to use:

```
class Interface:
    def __init__(self, *args):

        if len(args) == 0:
            raise ValueError("a string or integer is required")

        self.a = None
        self.b = None

        for value in args:
            if type(value) == str:
                self.a = value
            elif type(value) == int:
                self.b = value
```

This code takes an infinite amount of arguments, and creates a list of all of them. It then loops through the list, assigning the data to the corresponding variable. Although if multiple values of the same data type are used as arguments, the last argument of that type will be used.

e.g. If we use `x = Interface("a", "b")`, `x.a` will equal `"b"`

Comment: Thanks Elijah, I've clarified my question below in response to another answer. 

I think what I was hoping for was something like dict deconstruction. That is, define a dict `T` containing the types of `a` and `b` and then pass that to the function definition: `def func(i: **T)`, but this does not seem to be supported :(